# Nested random effects and interaction terms in lme4

Tags: r, random-effects-model, nested-data, lme4-nlme

I have a data set containing various vegetation and geomorphic variables sampled in 3 `distances` on both `sides` of 43 drainage ditches (`Location`). Roughly half of these ditches are occupied by a beaver, the other half is empty. Now I want to run a model with the binomial response variable `Status` ("beaver == 1" / "beaver == 0")

I'm struggling with the order and layout of the nested and interaction effects using `glmer`. So far I've got

```
fit <- glmer(Status ~ BankslopeScaled + Connectivity + 
                      Canal_width + Distance:Food_crops + 
                      Distance:Edible_trees + 
                (1 | Distance/Side/Location), 
              data, family=binomial(link="logit")
```

but I'm not sure if I still have pseudoreplication in my data or whether I correctly applied the formula in order to estimate the influence of the predictors in every `distance` on both `sides` in each `Location`.

Like, if `food_crops` in the 3rd `distance` on the left `side` is lower than `edible_trees` in the 2nd `distance` on the right `side`, then ...

I feel like there's something wrong with my random effects-term.

My output looks like this:

```
summary(fit)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Status ~ BankslopeScaled + Connectivity + Canal_width + Distance:Food_crops +  
Distance:Edible_trees + (1 | Distance/Side/Location)
Data: Satz

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   314.6    360.8   -144.3    288.6      245 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.18541 -0.71205  0.07243  0.82483  1.75303 

Random effects:
 Groups                   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Location:(Side:Distance) (Intercept) 2.834e-02 1.683e-01
 Side:Distance            (Intercept) 2.074e-10 1.440e-05
 Distance                 (Intercept) 2.085e-10 1.444e-05
 Number of obs: 258, groups:  Location:(Side:Distance), 258; Side:Distance, 6; Distance, 3

 Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept)            -2.86517    0.79747  -3.593 0.000327 ***
 BankslopeScaled         1.76475    0.62541   2.822 0.004776 ** 
 Connectivity            0.10394    0.02729   3.809 0.000140 ***
 Canal_width             0.19138    0.11089   1.726 0.084364 .  
 Distance1:Food_crops    0.03667    0.09366   0.391 0.695441    
 Distance2:Food_crops    0.10852    0.08996   1.206 0.227694    
 Distance3:Food_crops    0.06303    0.08502   0.741 0.458510    
 Distance1:Edible_trees  0.02273    0.01327   1.712 0.086818 .  
 Distance2:Edible_trees -0.01750    0.02992  -0.585 0.558738    
 Distance3:Edible_trees  0.09769    0.07986   1.223 0.221201    
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 [correlation of fixed effects snipped]
```

A point into the right direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A few things to keep in mind:

- You probably shouldn't treat `Distance` as a random effect in any case (estimates of random effects with only 3 levels are very unreliable)
- You already implicitly have the main effects of `Distance` in your model through the `Distance:Food_crops` and `Distance:Edible_trees` interactions.
- ... for both these reasons, you should leave `Distance` out of your random-effects specification: `(1 | Distance:Side) + (1 | Distance:Side:Location)` should work to include the two lower nested levels.
- you will still probably find that the `(1|Distance:Side)` random effect has variance of effectively zero ... but you might as well leave it in.

Comment: Tanks a lot!! 
The random effect variance of `(1|Distance:Side)` is indeed actually zero. And so is is `(1|Distance:Side:Location)`. That's peculiar... And another thing came to my mind: Most of the time, `Edible_trees` and `Food_crops` and other variables differed hugely on both `Sides` of one `Location`, regardless of their apparant promximity to each other. So, `Side` does not necessarily have to be included as a random effect after all, although I feel I somehow should tell the model that there are 2 `Sides` in each `Location`.
Is there a possibility to account for that?
Thanks again.

Comment: edit: `Side` should not be a random effect anyways. I just have to weave that in somehow.