# Nested effect in GLM

Tags: r, random-effects-model

I am sorry that my question repeats many others already available here. However I have read many of them (e.g. [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144904/nested-random-effects-and-interaction-terms-in-lme4), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192934/random-effects-fixed-effects-or-perhaps-nested-fixed-effects?rq=1) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79360/mixed-effects-model-with-nesting)) as well as other documents and I am still not sure about my model.

I have the following sampling protocol. I study the effect of crop species (e.g. wheat, barley, ...) and other parameters (e.g. humidity) on vegetation.

- I have 4 different crops.
- For each crop we randomly chose 5 plots (independant one to each other).
- In each plot we sampled 5 microplots to measure species richness and humidity (1 measurement per microplot).
- For some other measurements (e.g. abundance) we went one level further, with 25 squares in each microplot (1 measurement per square).

The 5 microplots within each plot (and the squares within each microplot) are not independant. So I should use random, nested effectsto avoid pseudoreplication.

```
# Microplot level
modAb = glmer(Richness ~ Crop + Humidity (1|Crop/Plot), family = poisson)
# Square level
modAb = glmer(Abundance ~ Crop + Humidity (1|Crop/Plot/Microplot), family = poisson)
```

But I have quite few observations, and I read that random effects in such situation were not very appropriate.

So is it the proper way to do it? Should I rather average my results on each plot?

Any confirmation / guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is `Crop` associated with a specific field / site / block? Otherwise, I don't understand why you group the random effects by it. In my (practical) experience, n = 5 can be sufficient for estimating a random effect, although you should keep in mind that you estimate a variance and that estimate is quite susceptible to outliers if n is small.

Comment: @Roland: each plot belongs to one crop only, but there are 5 plots per crop type. I thought I had to let the Crop in from other examples I read, but was quite unsure about it (it does not change the results). So is the correct formula `modAb = glmer(Richness ~ Crop + Humidity (1|Plot), family = poisson)` ?

Comment: I believe so but might be missing something. It would be very unusual to have the same variable as a fixed effect and as a grouping factor of random effects.